# Angular - Multiple controllers using ControllerAs in route

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui

I have an issue which I will go on to explain.  When using ControllerAS at the top of a html page such like this:

```
<div ng-controller="MyController as myControllerVM">
```

I can refer to things in my controller using the myControllerVM name.

Ie in my controller I set up a variable this and assign other variables to it like this:

```
var vm = this; 
vm.number = 1;
```

I can then refer to this variable in the html like this:

```
myControllerVM.number
```

as long as at the top of my page I have

```
 <div ng-controller="MyController as myControllerVM">
```

What I want to do is accomplish the same thing only through routing.  I have tried this:

```
.when(myROUTE, {
            templateUrl: 'template.html',
            controller: 'MyController',
            controllerAs: 'myControllerVM'
```

and assigned everything in the controller to the variable `vm` which points to `this` as before.  But in my html page these values are not getting pulled through as they were when the "controller as" name as at the top of the html page,  i.e. I can no longer refer to the values in the html as `myControllerVM.name` (the value isn't being pulled through).   The reason I need it in the route is because I want to use different controllers for the one html page.

Why isn't using `controllerAs` in the route working.

Comment: Can you post the template.html in this case?

Comment: It should work. You probably have some other issue that you haven't posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see all your code but you can find working example here

http://plnkr.co/edit/aedTeP2DbicGYwdGWKvU?p=preview

ie:

```
myApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  //
  // For any unmatched url, redirect to /state1
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/state1");
  //
  // Now set up the states
  $stateProvider
    .state('state1', {
      url: "/state1",
      templateUrl: "state1.html",
      controller: 'state1Ctrl',
      controllerAs:'vm'
    })

    .state('state2', {
      url: "/state2/",
      templateUrl: "state2.html",
      controller: 'state2Ctrl',
      controllerAs:'vm'



    });
});

myApp.controller('state2Ctrl', function(){
  var vm = this;
  vm.title= "That is my second"

});

myApp.controller('state1Ctrl', function($scope){
  var vm = this;
  vm.title= "fist controller";


});
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I appreciate both of the replies given greatly.  Your example showed me I was doing something very silly and had a small typo that I couldnt see at all.  I guess I was looking at the screen for far to long and just couldnt see it.  Your working example is brilliant though and I hope it will help others like it did me.  Thank you both very much.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing everything correct with

```
.when(myROUTE, {
            templateUrl: 'template.html',
            controller: 'MyController',
            controllerAs: 'myControllerVM'
```

I'm not sure if Angular documentation is clear enough on that, but the scope of router's current controller is `ngView`'s scope. So you can use `MyController` scope variables (including the ones that use `myControllerVM` identifier) only in template or `ngView` element attributes. I guess it is the source of the problem.